# 2-categorical Yoneda embedding and limits

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Does the 2-categorical Yoneda embedding defined in A.2 Section 5 of [`A study in derived algebraic geometry'](http://math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/Straightening.pdf) (Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum, version of 2018-11-14) preserve limits for any $(\infty,2)$-category? If not in general, does this hold for the $(\infty,2)$-category of DG-categories with continuous functors?